# Matching LaTeX Commands and convert them to XML tags

Tags: c#, regex, latex

I am trying to extract all the latex commands from a tex file and then convert the command to an xml tag. I have to use C# for this.

I am currently can match commands using this regex

`\\(?<command>(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[*=']?))(?<param>\[.+\])*(?<content>\{.+?}{1,2})`

which is currently can match most of commands like `\command{foobar}`, `\command[param]{foobar}` and `\command[param]{foobar}{foobar}` and replace these matches with `<command attr1="param">content</command>`, but I have a problem in matching nested commands

For Example

`\firstcommand{\secondcommand{nestedcontent} outercontent}` should be replaced to `<firstcommand><secondcommand>nestedcontent</secondcommand> outercontent</firstcommand>` but I can not match this pattern with my regex

My last try was trying to use PCRE.NET Library to use this regex `\\(?<command>(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[*=']?))(?<param>\[.+\])*(\{(?<content>(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+)\})` for recursive matching, but I got this exception `PCRE.PcreMatchException: 'match limit exceeded'` which obviously means that it can not match many nested patterns.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you showed, you can try

```cs
var text = @"\firstcommand{\secondcommand{nestedcontent} outercontent}";
var pattern = @"\\(\w+)\{([^{}]*)}";
var prev = string.Empty;
do {
    prev = text;
    text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "<$1>$2</$1>");
} while (prev != text);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

It is basically matching and replacing innermost `word{...}` substrings.
See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/1chWIq). The `\\(\w+)\{([^{}]*)}` pattern matches

- `\\` - a backslash
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more word chars (letters, digits, underscore)
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` -  a `}` char.

**NOTE**: This won't work if you have other `{` or `}` in between `\\\w+\{` and `}` parts. Using a dedicated parser for arbitrary strings in this format will be a solution.